# How to understand Flink exactly-once and at-least-once semantics

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm new to Flink and currently exploring Fault Tolerance in the framework. I'm aware that Flink provides both Exactly-Once and At-Least-Once semantics for ensuring fault tolerance.
After reading this [post](https://flink.apache.org/2020/10/15/from-aligned-to-unaligned-checkpoints-part-1-checkpoints-alignment-and-backpressure/) and this [documentation](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/learn-flink/fault_tolerance/), I have a basic understanding that checkpoint barriers are employed to achieve this.

Is there a simple example to check the difference between these two semantics intuitively?

I've tried something like consuming data from a Kafka topic(which all messages are integers), calculate window sum, and at some point trigger an error to restart the task.
Let's say the Kafka producer produces one integer per second and my flink program set checkpoint every 3 seconds and calculate sum every 3 seconds. For example:

`1,2,3(checkpoint),4,5(error),6...`

My process code is following:

```
DataStream<Tuple2<String, Long>> sumData = data.flatMap(new customProcess())
.keyBy(value -> value.f0)
.window(TumblingProcessingTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(3)))
.sum(1)
.print()
```

My understanding is that if I use *exactly-once* then it should print **6(1+2+3)** and **15(4+5+6)**, and if I use *at-least-once* it should print **6(1+2+3)** and **19(4+4+5+6)** since after restarting, **message 4** will be re-processed. But my code does not show this result.

Do I misunderstand something or my code is not correct? Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For results to be deterministic you have to use event time, not processing time. Try that first, then report back.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind with at-least-once, duplicates are possible, but not guaranteed. And even with event time processing, whether or not duplication will occur depends on non-deterministic race conditions between the parallel instances of the operators involved.